# React Native release apk doesn't match app when running react-native run-android

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I'm currently building my first React Native app. I set up a release in Play Console for Internal Testing and was able to push my first signed apk. Since then, we've made bug fixes that are now merged into master. When I try to generate a new release by running:

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

and upload as a new release, I don't see any of the new changes after updating my app via the Play Store.

I've tried running

```
react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

before generating a new release, but I still don't see the changes.

Running react-native run-android while my device is hooked up with USB Debugging works fine, as well as in any emulator.  I just can't figure out why my APK doesn't match the code generated on my local device.

Is there a step that I'm missing that's keeping my APK from representing the latest changes on master when I build?

Using React Native 0.56

Updated to add my Gradle Config:

```
 // android/app/build.grade
 signingConfigs {
    release {
        if(project.hasProperty('MY_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MY_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword pass
            keyAlias MY_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword pass
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should update the android\app\build.gradle file under the app folder by placing this code under the defaultConfig

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file('debug.keystore')
        keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
        keyPassword 'android'
        storePassword 'android'
    }

    release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
```

Also within android\app\build.gradle, ensure your buildTypes for release includes the correct signingConfig line.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Just like that and update your gradle.properties file with these properties

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE="Key Store Name"
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS="Key Store alias"
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD="Key Store Password"
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD="Key Password"
```

Comment: Oh yes! I didn't have a debug keystore in my build.gradle file. I've added it now, but when I try to run react-native run-android, i'm getting an error that the signatures don't match previously installed version `Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.noblr_android signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!`

Comment: I just had to uninstall the app from my emulator. 
This may be a dumb question, but now that I'm generating a debug apk, I can't upload it on the play console to distribute to my team that i've added as an internal test group. Is it possible to distribute debug apks to an internal test team? Or can I just increase versions of my release to continue rolling out to the internal test?

Comment: You have to increase the version of your release in order to distribute it online and generate release apk by following commands

cd android then 
gradlew assembleRelease

Comment: I've done that as well. I'm able to upload the new generated apk with a new version code but when i update the app on my phone it either force stops or shows the outdated version. I'm updating version code as well as version name in my build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
--entry-file ./index.js
```

to

```
--entry-file ./index.android.js
```

Comment: From what I understand, index.android.js was used in earlier versions of React Native. I'm currently using 0.56 and my entry file is index.js

Answer (score 0):

maybe its late but I hope this save someone :
It looks like you have to rebundle it whenever you add new module or asset

> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res